# How to create row/subject index in longitudinal data

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal data formatting like below. I want to create an index for each subject regarding their 'disease' status. If disease status is NA or 0, the index would be 0; if disease status is 1, the index would be 1.

However, I want each row within the same subject to have the same index, disregard at what observational point their status is. Say, as long as the individual has 'disease=1' disregard which row, the index should be 1 for all rows for that individual.

Anybody has good ideas?
Thank!

> ```
> id disease  index
> 1    NA      0
> 1    NA      0
> 1    NA      0
> 2    NA      1
> 2     1      1
> 2     1      1
> 3    NA      1
> 3    NA      1
> 3     1      1
> 4     1      1
> 4     0      1
> 4     0      1
> 5     0      0
> 5     0      0
> 5     0      0
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. FOr some reason your image (which had a screencap of your data?) did not appear. This is probably for the best: all SO questions should include a reproducible example. One way to do this is to include code which generates a fake data set, with the properties of your real data set. Another option is to use `dput` to paste your objects into your question. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here:  http://bit.ly/SORepro   .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### assuming dat is your data

#### using `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat)

DT[, index := as.numeric(sum(disease >= 1, na.rm=TRUE)>0), by=id]
```

---

#### using Base `R`

```
INDX <- tapply(dat$disease, dat$id, function(x) 
             as.numeric(sum(x >= 1, na.rm=TRUE)>0))

INDX <- data.frame(id=names(INDX), index=INDX)
dat <- merge(dat, INDX)
```